# In corda do we give file path as string?

Tags: corda

In corda inside my flow i directly give file path as a string then I convert that to file using file reader.Then I read that file in one string,put that string in state.
Its deployed properly But while making the transaction is shows error. Is it possible to add file path as a string in corda??

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload the file as an attachment. Like this: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Features/attachment-sendfile/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/examples/sendfile/flows/SendAttachment.java#L73

If you are specifically looking for content of the file, you will mostly read the file in a contract like this:

```
// Extract the blacklisted company names from the JAR.
        List<String> blacklistedCompanies = new ArrayList<>();
        JarInputStream attachmentJar = attached.openAsJAR();
        try {
            while (!attachmentJar.getNextEntry().getName().equals("blacklist.txt")) {
                // Calling 'getNextEntry()' causes us to scroll through the JAR.
            }
            InputStreamReader isrBlacklist = new InputStreamReader(attachmentJar, Charsets.UTF_8);
            BufferedReader brBlacklist = new BufferedReader(isrBlacklist, (8 * 1024)); // Note - changed BIR to BR

            String company = brBlacklist.readLine();

            while (company != null) {
                blacklistedCompanies.add(company);
                company = brBlacklist.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error reading blacklist.txt");
        }
```